# FSRM - Setting File Screen to block files types that are already inside some folders

Tags: file-sharing, windows

I have a file server without any kind of file screen to prevent users from saving certain types of files in their folders. Our management changed and now I have to apply file screens to block some file types like pictures, audio, etc on most of the folders, with some exceptions.

The thing is most of the users folders already have all those kind of files saved inside it.

Is there a problem setting the file screens with those files already in there? My idea is to prevent new users to save more files in there and then manage like move or delete the old files.

Is it viable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, setting a File Screen will only apply going forward. I recently did this at my workplace, and can confirm that existing files were not affected. However, this also means they cannot modify existing files that are part of the file screen.

File Screen to block .exe's on the J:\ drive:
[image]

Existing .exe on the J:\ drive:
[image]

Trying to copy a .exe to that folder:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked as expected.
Also solved my problems with large backlogs

Answer (score 0):

It won't affect currently existing files.

It will simply prevent new ones from being added.

You can test this yourself, just make a demo folder and put a file in there, then create a filter for that file's extension. You won't be able to make new ones, but the existing will remain.